# Bancha Equivalent for Java (and Ext.js/Sencha Touch)

Tags: java, extjs, model, sencha-touch, integration

I'm used to building Ext.js (or Sencha Touch) apps with a [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) backend using [Bancha](http://banchaproject.org/). Basically Bancha will generate the frontend (Ext.js) model classes based on the backend (CakePHP) model classes and will provide an easy way to make calls to backend functions from the client.

Is there a similar (preferably open source) project achieving the same goal in the Java world?

edit : 
We'll use the Spring framework on the server side.

Comment: Does Sencha's GXT product accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: I looked at GXT a bit, but from what I understood GXT does too much for what we're trying to accomplish.
We basically would like a Bridge between Spring (Java) and Ext.js backend/frontend model classes.
We're probably going to create a RESTful API using Spring and connect the frontend models to it. It's a step more than the Bancha implementation, but it will do the trick.